# E_NOINTERFACE returned

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have a COM Client and a COM Server, the COM Server holds an Interface exposed by the client, now the client is actually just an EXE, how do I make sure that the Interface exposed by the client is visible to the Server?

Because when I call CoCreateInstance now on that interface in the server I get a E_NOINTERFACE and I suspect it's because there is no Proxy/stub dll for the client registered on the system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `E_NOINTERFACE` can be returned if COM can't marshal the interface. You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to try to find what exactly is happening.

Comment: so I've checked the registry and the IID is present of the Interface, it however still returns the error, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: In ProcMon the first time it queries the Key it says 'BUFFER TOO SMALL'

Comment: Okay, IID is present, so what? What if COM tries to find proxy/stub and fails? You shouldn't expect that you just look onto Process Monitor output for a moment and immediately see what's wrong.